# Error al parsear json android

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

resulta que tengo un problema con un json que traigo de un php el cual tiene el siguiente formato:

[{"tope_v_1":"1017900","tope_v_2":"590000","tope_v_3":"230000","val_1":"1017724","val_2":"545910","val_3":"213820"}]

lo que no he podido es parsearlo en java con android porque me sale en siguiente error:

JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONobject

y el codigo java es el siguiente:

```
 try {
                            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject((Map) response);

                            valor = jObject.getString("val_1");

                            String mensaje = " valor: " + valor ;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                          //  Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this,"res: "+ vls1 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this,"ERROR: " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
```

Espero me puedan colaborar gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que el formato del JSON que estas recibiendo es un objeto (JSONObject) dentro de un arreglo(JSONArray), si te fijas lo tienes dentro de dos corchetes `[]`.

Si no es necesario que este como un arreglo, debes quitarle esos `[]`. Por el contrario sí lo necesitas como un arreglo, solo tienes que recibirlo como un JSONArray en vez de un JSONObject.

Comment: Hola, si lo tenia sin corchetes pero tampoco me funciona